# PHP 5.4.4 unrecognized --enable-dbase

Tags: php, php-extension, dbase

I'm trying to compile php 5.4.4 on a CentOS 6.1 x64 server with --enable-dbase option but instead I receive this error:
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-dbase

I saw that in the ./ext/ dir there's no dbase folder so I downloaded the source from http://pecl.php.net/package/dbase. Still, the same error. Does anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for the `--enable-dbase` option?

Comment: I always compiled PHP with --enable-dbase. I have another production server with php 5.2.13 and the extension is enabled. Anyway, here are the installation instructions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/dbase.installation.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dbase` extension [was removed from the PHP distribution in 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.removed-extensions.php).

[You need to install it directly from PECL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php), *after* compiling PHP.

Comment: For my CentOS I had to run `pear install pecl/dbase` and then it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

test if you use Linux distro Ubuntu or Debian

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
sudo pecl install dbase
```

(optional if you php vertions  > 5.5 and show error run -> sudo pecl install -Z dbase )

create file

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/dbase.ini
```

and add this line in dbase.ini `extension=dbase.so`

(add lib extension dbase.so in php.ini)
`sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` add line `extension=dbase.so`

```
sudo service apache2 restar
```

and test your functions in php.
to me it worked, I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you now have to install it via pecl or pear instead of having it done when compiling php source, maybe the manual hasn't been updated yet